# RST sequence number and window size

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpip, sockets

RFC793 states the following about RST processing:

> In all states except SYN-SENT, all reset (RST) segments are validated
>   by checking their SEQ-fields. A reset is valid if its sequence number
>   is in the window.

But I'm not sure what does this statement means exactly. Let's say I have the following scenario:

[image: Image 1]

So socket 2 tells socket 1 that its window size is 6 KB, and then socket 1 sends 6 KB worth of data to socket 2.

And then socket 1 sends an RST packet to socket 2:

[image: Image 2]

What will happen in this case, will the RST packet be accepted by socket 2?

Answer (score 1):

Linux only tear down a TCP connection if the RST sequence number is the next expected sequence number. This rule was applied to avoid blind TCP reset attack (see [RFC 5961 section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5961#section-3.2)). So the following rules are applied :

> 1. If the RST bit is set and the sequence number is outside the
>    current receive window, silently drop the segment.
> 2. If the RST bit is set and the sequence number exactly matches
>    the
>    next expected sequence number (RCV.NXT), then TCP MUST reset the
>    connection.
> 3. If the RST bit is set and the sequence number does not exactly
>    match the next expected sequence value, yet is within the current
>    receive window (RCV.NXT < SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND), TCP MUST
>    send an acknowledgment (challenge ACK):
>
>    <SEQ=SND.NXT><ACK=RCV.NXT><CTL=ACK>

So you are in case 1, your RST segment will be silently drop (at least on Linux, this is implementation dependent but SHOULD be respected).

Answer (score 0):

Once all the data is transferred from client to destination with the fragment mechanism using the MTU value, FIN will be initiated not the RST.

- FIN: Data transfer is complected and no more pkts left. (Graceful closure)
- RST: I am not listing on this port / I am overloaded. (Force close)

For RST packet yes sequence number is validated because src, dst and intermediate devices should kill the session and the connection / state table entry.